# How can I retrieve data from all sub-nodes of a node from Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database that looks like this
[image: database]

I want to retrieve data from all months of 2022.
I have a code that retrieves data from 2022 February that looks like this

```
  val reference =  database.getReference("users").child(uid).child("Incomes").child("2022").child("February")
        reference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val adapter = GroupAdapter<GroupieViewHolder>()
                snapshot.children.forEach{
                    val expenseElement = it.getValue(ExpenseInHome::class.java)
                    if (expenseElement!=null){
                        adapter.add(ExpenseItemForHomeScreen(expenseElement))
                    }
                    incomeHomeRecycler.adapter = adapter
                }
            }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })
```

My intention is to get data from all months not just February. If I write

```
val reference = database.getReference("users").child(uid).child("Incomes").child("2022")
```

I get an error.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You see that I have itemName,itemValue etc. Well if I try to retrieve that data from 2022 it gives error because those values exist in its subnode not in 2022.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your current code works for a single month, you can expand it to process all months in a year by adding an extra loop:

```
val reference =  database.getReference("users").child(uid).child("Incomes").child("2022")
reference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        val adapter = GroupAdapter<GroupieViewHolder>()
        snapshot.children.forEach{ //  loop over months in year
            it.children.forEach{
                val expenseElement = it.getValue(ExpenseInHome::class.java)
                if (expenseElement!=null){
                    adapter.add(ExpenseItemForHomeScreen(expenseElement))
                }
            }
        }
        incomeHomeRecycler.adapter = adapter
    }
    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        throw error.toException(); //  never ignor errors
    }
})
```

Comment: It did not work. I changed the date on the emulator so I can add items to different month. This time on my recyclerview it only showed items of the last added month items. In this situation it gave only the incomes of march it did not show the items from month February.  And if I delete the node of month march and restart the program it gives me items of february once again. So this solution somehow gives the items of last added subnode of 2022

Comment: Ah yeah... the adapter was still being created in the wrong place. I updated the code in my answer, but also strongly recommend running the code in a debugger and stepping through the `ValueEventListener` if this sort of problem happens again.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible with a database structure like this. In my opinion the best thing you can do is think the database in a different way, organizing in another specific field what you want to get

Comment: I thought about that too.  I can do something like this: When adding data to database I can add duplicate data for example: Instead of adding data only to users/uid/Expenses/year/month I can add the same data also to users/uid/Expenses/year 
And I can use each one for specific needs. What do you think about this solution

Comment: I had mor or less the same problems and organizing in a different ways the database saves a lot of time for me. I did exactly what you suggest (duplicate) and it was fine for me (obviously, if your query is referred in a year. If you have another query - for example 10 years - this structure will not solve the problem)

Comment: Yeah that is right. I am trying to retrieve the data only from current year which will not be a problem